# Apache Phoenix query server thin client with Kerberos

Tags: hadoop, hbase, kerberos, apache-phoenix

I'm trying to setup Apache Phoenix QueryServer in secure HBase environment.
My hbase-site.xml is:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.wal.codec</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.IndexedWALEditCodec</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>zk1,zk2,zk3</value>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
    <value>kerberos</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>phoenix.queryserver.keytab.file</name>
    <value>/usr/lib/apache-phoenix-queryserver/bin/phoenix.keytab</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>phoenix.queryserver.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>rwqueryserver/_HOST@FOO.BAR</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>phoenix.queryserver.http.keytab.file</name>
    <value>/usr/lib/apache-phoenix-queryserver/bin/phoenix.keytab</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>phoenix.queryserver.http.kerberos.principal</name>
    <value>rwqueryserver/_HOST@FOO.BAR</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Query server is starting without any problems.

```
2018-12-12 09:13:07,353 INFO org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.server.QueryServer: Login successful.
```

I checked KDC side and I can see logins from the principal used for server/client connections. No errors on KDC side as well.
Thin client command is:

```
./sqlline-thin.py 'http://dns-of-query-server:8765;principal="rwqueryserver/dns-of-query-server@DATASYS.CF.WTF";keytab="/usr/lib/apache-phoenix-queryserver/bin/phoenix.keytab"'
```

I tried to use user's principal and server's principal - situation is the same.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute HTTP Request, got HTTP/404
```

From the queryserver log:

```
2018-12-12 09:15:30,987 WARN org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.security.SpnegoLoginService: 
GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:856)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
        at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:906)
        at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:556)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.security.SpnegoLoginService.login(SpnegoLoginService.java:137)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.login(LoginAuthenticator.java:61)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.SpnegoAuthenticator.validateRequest(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:99)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:512)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: KrbException: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:278)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:149)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:108)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:829)
        ... 19 more
```

When I'm trying to use non-existing principal I'm getting different errors.
I checked JCE - it's installed.

```
jrunscript -e 'print (javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES") >= 256);'
true
```

Can you advice anything ?

Comment: Ok, I'm using query-server & thin-client on the same VM (same java version).
In queryserver logs I can see 
```19/02/05 12:12:52 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/02/05 12:12:52 INFO server.QueryServer: Login successful.```
That means that queryserver itself able to use keytab file and authenticate with Kerberos. But when I'm trying to connect with client I'm getting error described above (keytabs for server and client were generated at the same way)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a match to a known Java bug.

Please refer; https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6907425

Have a look at the above documentation and try again with an up to date JDK version.

Comment: I tried to use even OpenJDK - the same thing.
```java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b10, mixed mode)```